# Facing issue with C# client of Apache pulsar getting faulted

Tags: apache-pulsar

I am working on incorporating Pulsar C# client library and facing issues with integrating the library.
If I call "producer.Send", its getting faulted.

```
public class PulsarProducerExample
{
   
    private const string Topic = "persistent://public/default/my-topic";

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        // Create a Pulsar client
        var client = PulsarClient.Builder().ServiceUrl(new Uri("pulsar://pulsar:6650")).Build();
        Console.WriteLine("Created the new client");

        // Create a producer on the desired topic
        var producer = client.NewProducer()
                             .Topic(Topic)
                             .Create();
        Console.WriteLine("Created the new producer");
        try
        {
            // Send messages to the topic
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var message = $"Message {i}";
                await producer.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
                Console.WriteLine($"Sent: {message}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the producer and the client
            await producer.DisposeAsync();
            await client.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I see output as "Exception: Producer has faulted". Can someone help here as to what could be the cause behind this?

Comment: Post the full exception text, not just the message part. The full text contains any inner exceptions and a stack trace with the chain of calls that caused the error. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()` or by passing the exception object to a format string, eg `Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex}");

Comment: This issue was caused by docker network not being properly used and docker compose was not used to create the default network. After doing this change things started working.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by not setting up the proper docker network. I was using the container name which was not working. So , created a docker compose file that helped me create the network where all three producer, consumer and cluster itself can reside.